# CRS Projection problems prevent spatial merge in R

Tags: r, coordinate-system, merge

Here is an updated sense of where I'm at. I decided to re-read in my data file using ReadOGR.

```
MyDataFile <- read.csv("reduced1.csv")
class(MyDataFile)
coordinates(MyDataFile)<-~X+Y
class(MyDataFile)

writeOGR(MyDataFile, "Folder", "File", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
proj4string(MyDataFile)
```

Checking the CRS at this point gives me 'NA' so I try and assign it

```
Redefined <- readOGR(dsn="Folder", layer = "File")
proj4string(Redefined) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS 84
```

> [1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
>   +towgs84=0,0,0"

Now for reading in my boundaries file:

```
Map <-readOGR(".","infuse_dist_lyr_2011")
proj4string(Map)
```

> [1] "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000
>   +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894"

So now to transform.

```
NewMap <- spTransform(Map, proj4string(Redefined))
```

Comment: The `CRS` function doesn't apply to sp-class objects, its applied to strings to create CRS objects. Use `proj4string(map)` or `raster::projection(map)` to get the projection string of an sp-class object. That's where your warning comes from.

Comment: And does `CRS(map)` really give an error about `CRS(h)`? We care about precision here...

Comment: Apolgies you're correct - I changed the name to map for the purposes of this post but omitted to do so consistently - sorry!

Comment: Also proj4string returns strings which seem to suggest my files are in the right CRS. However the exact string is slightly different each time - wondering if this matters? I.e for my datafile "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" whereas for my shapefile +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" - the latter being shorted and without the zone and unit bits.

Comment: Those are completely different projections - one is lat-long in degrees, the other is UTM in metres. Suggest you now edit your question and show us exactly what you are doing - but `spTranform(map1, proj4string(map2))` should return `map1` projected to the same CRS ad `map2`...

Comment: Thanks, will rewrite - just to let you know though that trying spTransform gives me: ` Error: non finite transformation detected:
[1] 291902.5 196289.6      Inf      Inf
Error in .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  : 
  failure in Polygons 1 Polygon 1 points 1
In addition: Warning message:
In .spTransform_Polygon(input[[i]], to_args = to_args, from_args = from_args,  :
  8073 projected point(s) not finite`

Comment: That sounds like you've got the wrong proj4string assigned to some data. If you read with `readOGR` or `raster::shapefile` it should pick up the projection from the .prj file. In your rewrite, show the output of `summary` on your spatial objects.

Comment: I think I've got confused about theCRS I have. I started with a file of CSV data which is points which I wanted to assign to polygons. The format of the XY data is like this: 57.538932 -2.4623 (a point somewhere in Aberdeenshire, Scotland). When I first added this file to ArcGis it seemed to detect the CRS as WGS 1984. I then have a boundaries shapefile which seemed to detect as British National Grid OSGB. My only goal has been to get them in the same format by converting the boundaries shapefile to WGS 1984. Have I missed something?

Comment: Now your question doesn't seem to have a problem in it... Does spTransform fail? What error?

Answer (score 4):

Try reading the layers using rgdal::readOGR , this reads the projection automatically and is (IMO) more robust that readShapePoly.

Then if needed, run spTransform with one of your layers as the "to" option.

Comment: Tom, I will try readOGR for my shapefile but what about my datafile initially read in from csv? Can readOGR be used?

Comment: Just to add that I followed the advice of using ReadOGR with both files. I then was able to use sp Transform into epsg:4238 for both. However for the datafile, which already had the right coordinates, the coordinate column has now gone awry. E.g the first entry reads -127.4887
0.00042064 where it used to be in degrees decimal

Comment: I'm slightly confused over what your problem is now. The co-ordinates will change to match to new projection system. Are the data appearing where you would expect when plotted?